# Vba code prevent deletion of cells that contain formula

Tags: excel, vba

Hy

I need to modify this code which prevent deletion of cells by range, to not allow deletion celks which contain formula.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:E7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo ExitPoint
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not IsDate(Target(1)) Then
    Application.Undo
    MsgBox " You can't delete cell contents from this range " _
    , vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
End If
```

ExitPoint:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: Did you try using [`Range.HasFormula`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasformula)?

Comment: I did, but can't make it work